# ubuntu server becomes unresponsive via web, ftp, ssh and more

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, server-crashes, ubuntu-11.04

I have a ubuntu server hosted and a couple of times it becomes unresponsive to everything, until a hard reboot is done.. i have pulled the logs but i need a little bit of help working out what they mean.. and if they are actually related or if you think it could be a hardware issue:

**syslog**

```
Mar  1 15:11:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24473]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:12:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24530]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:13:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24585]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:14:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24654]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:15:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24713]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:16:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24770]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:17:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24827]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:17:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24828]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar  1 15:17:05 xxxxxxxx postfix/pickup[23311]: 3CFEE2E3CF: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar  1 15:17:05 xxxxxxxx postfix/cleanup[24880]: 3CFEE2E3CF: message-id=<20130301151705.3CFEE2E3CF@xxxxxxxx.kimsufi.com>
Mar  1 15:17:05 xxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[3886]: 3CFEE2E3CF: from=<root@xxxxxxxx.kimsufi.com>, size=2080, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  1 15:17:05 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtp[24882]: 3CFEE2E3CF: to=<danny@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com>, relay=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dyndns.org[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=0.56, delays=0.08/0/0.21/0.26, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0  <20130301151705.3CFEE2E3CF@xxxxxxxx.kimsufi.com> Queued mail for delivery)
Mar  1 15:17:05 xxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[3886]: 3CFEE2E3CF: removed
Mar  1 15:18:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24897]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:19:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24944]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:20:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[24999]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 15:21:01 xxxxxxxx CRON[25046]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 35 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: imklog 4.6.4, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.4" x-pid="3425" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: Linux version 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 (root@kernel-64.ovh.net) (gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 09:48:59 UTC 2012
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: Command line: root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 BOOT_IMAGE=bzImage-2.6-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009d800 (usable)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000000009d800 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000df790000 (usable)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000df790000 - 00000000df79e000 (ACPI data)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000df79e000 - 00000000df7d0000 (ACPI NVS)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000df7d0000 - 00000000df7e0000 (reserved)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000df7ec000 - 00000000f0000000 (reserved)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000 (reserved)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000ffc00000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000620000000 (usable)
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Mar  1 16:02:40 xxxxxxxx kernel: DMI present.
```

As you can see, the server stops right after a cronjob has run.. there are no complicated jobs running on here..

Are there any pointers you can give me on diagnosing the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]

[That would be a confirmed bug in your version of Ubuntu,](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2011-September/025382.html) so I'd hope that's what causing the issue, and try to resolve it first.

You could upgrade to get around it, [or try what's suggested here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/830046), which would be editing your `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file (or running `apt-get upgrade`).

Failing that, stop running the cron job that occurs just before the server hangs and take a look at it to see what it might be doing that could cause your server to hang.  If nothing else, fixing the `rsyslog` bug might allow you to capture some useful logging info that could point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your reply, my first thoughts were update kernel (which i done), apt-get update & update & dist-update (which i done - but found no updates) .. so i have now changed that line  like your suggestion.. should i reboot the server to re-load the config?

Comment: I removed one of the cronjobs - how can i tell from that log which cron actually run? as i have 2 in there - but non  are set to run at that time?!

Comment: i rebooted and looked at the logs again and that line does not appear so that's a good sign.. i will monitor and hopefully it'll be that which was the issue.. thanks for your help